# User can't resize DataGridView columns

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with the datasource set to a binding source of data. My problem is I cannot get *most* of the columns to resize. Several of the columns don't show a resize cursor, while two others do: one can be resized, one cannot.

Here is what I have tried:

- `DGV.AllowUsertoResizeColumns = True`
- `DGV.AutoSizeColumnMode = None`
- `DGV.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = EnableResizing`
- `DGV.Dock = Fill`
- All Columns having `AutoSizeMode = NoneSet` and `Resizable = True`
- The DGV is embedded in a panel of a SplitContainer, yet after bringing it to front, the others to back, or other random combinations, still unable to resize
- Using `dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader)` (and other variations) after data has been loaded into the DGV
- While I'm able to resize one of the columns, the settings in the Columns collection are no different from the others

Here's a screenshot of the properties of my [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_properties(v=vs.110).aspx):

[image: DataGridView Properties]

Any Ideas?

Comment: `I can print off my settings list for the control` - include as much information as possible. If you can publish a reduced case for the problem your described, that could help.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not. It's the strangest thing. When this change is needed, I'll probably just delete the control and re-create it.

Comment: Have you tried searching your code to see if some of those properties are being set at run-time?

Comment: Can you please provide a screen-shot of the gridview and type of all the columns in it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Upon checking the individual column settings in the gridview, I found some cells still had

`AutoSizeMode = AllCells`

I changed this to:

**`AutoSizeMode = NotSet`**

and now I am able to resize all columns.

Comment: There is not NotSet setting for the AutoSizeMode property. None is the closest and the problem persists with this setting.

Comment: @ChadD The setting I am referencing is in the actual columns design view of the grid. There should be a setting called AutoSizeMode there that has a NotSet value available.

Comment: I was also able to use the setting `AutoSizeMode = Fill`

Comment: On my DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, the column was not resizable when I used myColumn.AutoSizeMode = NotSet.  I had to use the None option to get my column to be resizable.

Answer (score 3):

Set:

AutoSizeColumnsMode = none

[image]